# Getting older documents even after Deleting and closing database in Couch base lite

Tags: ios, swift, database-replication, couchbase-lite, couchapp

I am using couch base lite in an application having sign in /sign out support. By considering each user id as channel, we are creating the documents.Everything is working fine.

But on sign out and sign in using the new user, I am getting previously signed in user documents also, even if I delete and close the database on sign out.Checked by stopping replicators and recreating the views also.But no use.

I am using couch base lite 1.4.0 version.
Here are the APIs  I am calling when user signs out from the application.

```
self.pushReplication?.stop()
self.pullReplication?.stop()
self.publicPullReplication?.stop()

self.pushReplication = nil
self.pullReplication = nil
self.publicPullReplication = nil

try self.database.delete()
try self.database.close()
```

Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Delete drived data n delete your app from simulator/device. Clean your project and run again.

Comment: I am getting the issue in device also , not only in simulator.

Comment: delete your app clean your project and run again. bcz due to cache memory it replicates the data. So its better if you clean everything and again run the project.

Comment: Deleting the app is not a solution as I need to support sign-out. Every time I can't expect user to delete the app and install from App store for new Sign In.

Comment: Ok .. you have to maintain the DB structure according to that.

Comment: Shouldn't close and delete be the other way round... i.e. close and then delete.

Comment: @Shyam in cblite 2.10 i am facing same issue, did u find any solution on this?